# Unir 2 querys en la misma fila pero con diferente columna SQL

Tags: sql, join

Tengo 2 tablas de una misma base de datos, y en esas tablas necesito saber el numero de veces que aparece un evento, para ello tengo estos 2 query´s de esta forma:

```
select owner_id, count (owner_id) as total_order
from order_store
group by owner_id
```

```
select owner_id, count (owner_id) as total_visit
from events
group by owner_id
```

El owner_id es el mismo para las dos tablas y necesito unir las tablas de forma que cada fila quede el owner_id y tenga al lado otras dos columnas con el total de veces que que se repite en la tabla de events y el total de veces que se repite en la tabla orders y una tercera columna donde se dividan estos dos valores

ayuda por favor! GRACIAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te envio lo que yo hice cuando me tope con el mismo problema:

```
Select TABLA_A.owner_id,TABLA_A.total_order,TABLA_B.total_visit 
    FROM (select owner_id, count (owner_id) as total_order from order_store group by owner_id ) as TABLA_A
    INNER JOIN  (select owner_id, count (owner_id) as total_visit from events group by owner_id) AS TABLA_B
        ON TABLA_A.owner_id = TABLA_B.owner_id
```

yo le puse **inner** pero tu puedes puedes utilizar el **right o left** segun se te acomode, cualquier otra consulta por favor sin miedo.

En base a tu consulta para explicarte:

```
query1 = select owner_id, count (owner_id) as total_order from order_store group by owner_id 

query2 = select owner_id, count (owner_id) as total_visit from events group by owner_id
```

Se usa cada query como una tabla derivada y se une mediante un join (inner o full outer).

```
select A.* B.*
from (query_1) as A inner join (query_2) as B on A.num_doc = B.num_doc;
```

Si existe la posibilidad de que existe una fila en el uno y no en el otro entonces puedes usar FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Gracias! si sirve pero no entendí muy bien el procedimiento (soy nuevo) me podría explicar por favor cómo funciona?

Comment: Edite la respuesta para poder explicarte un poco, soy malo explicando pero espero me entiendas.

Comment: Excelente, funciona a la perfeccion esta solucion. muchas gracias.